# How to send large strings to another page, while also maintaining fast refreshing?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, apache, iframe

I am trying to setup a website with a preview of what you are typing. I have to have two pages, one of them has an HTML editor, and the second is in an `iframe` in the same page to display the output.

I need it to have instant updates when you type something into the editor so it is reflected on to the other page. I am using an `iframe` because I can't have the output on this page. This is because the page already has CSS which overrides what CSS you put into the editor.

I have tried using cookies but they have a character limit which is no good for what I am doing. I am looking for a way to send large strings from one page to another with no character limits and with speedy responses.

Any help would be amazing. Thank you.

Comment: `the page already has CSS which overrides what CSS you put into the editor` That's no reason to separate the page in an iframe. If your CSS is structured correctly you can easily have an element which uses styling rules separate from the main page body.

Comment: "This is because the page already has CSS which overrides what CSS you put into the editor"...why not use the same CSS for both? Then the user will see exactly how the final output will look, while they're editing it. Editors such as CKEditor can do that, for example.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan is absolutely correct (as almost always). However I want to add that working with an iframe should always be the last option to be considered. It's only good for specific situations. On topic though, why not use a database to store your large data?

Comment: I need the CSS to be separate. The page that the editor is on already has styling and I need the output to have no styling, except what is defined inside of the editor. This is intend that you can make your own projects on the website and have its own styling.